# PictureBox.Image with Interpolation and SmoothingMode

Tags: .net, graphics

The only way I know to draw an image to a picturebox without being jagged, is settings the Graphics to

```
    uGraphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    uGraphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
```

But the only way where I can do this is to do that inside a PictureBox_Paint event.

However, I would like to do it only once.

Does anybody spot where I did it wrong?

I was trying to do it like this:

```
PictureBoxSetImage(Me.picUserImage, Me.ILUserIcons.Images(sGUID))

Public Sub PictureBoxSetImage(ByRef uPic As PictureBox, ByRef uBMP As Bitmap)

    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(uBMP)
        modControls.GraphicsSetSmoothingMode(g)
        uPic.Image = uBMP
    End Using

End Sub

Public Sub GraphicsSetSmoothingMode(ByRef uGraphics As Graphics)

    uGraphics.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic
    uGraphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality

End Sub
```

With this approach, the image is still jagged. 
When I use the "Graphics" instead that the Paint event exposes, it works fine, and the picture is smoothed.

Can anyone help?

Comment: PictureBox does not expose these properties. To do it cleanly and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), derive a class from PictureBox, override the `OnPaint` event, and add the desired properties there.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you give an example? I never did that before.

Comment: See Jason D's answer in the linked duplicate.